# How to create a new column in a dataframe with the value of another column in that dataframe, but within 1 hour

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, with columns:

- ID
- DateTime
- Capacity

I want to add a new column to this dataframe, with the capacity within an hour.
For example, I have

```
ID Datetime           Capacity
1  20200101 12:23:10  435
```

So in the new column, I want the Capacity of the record of ID=1 and Datetime=13:23:10

Is there a statement to handle this?

Thanks already !

Answer (score 0):

You can add `1 hour` to original column, convert to strings `HH:MM:SS`, so possible filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
Datetime = '13:23:10'
ID = 1

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

df = df[(df['Datetime'] + pd.Timedelta('1H')).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').eq(Datetime) & df['ID'].eq(ID)]
print (df)
   ID            Datetime  Capacity
0   1 2020-01-01 12:23:10       43
```